# an example of a set for which the closure does not equal the union of the interior and accumulation points

Tags: general-topology

we know the closure is the union of the interior and boundary points , so it boils down to finding an example where there is a boundary point which is not an accumulation point. What is an example?

Comment: $\{0\}$: $(\operatorname{cl}\{0\})\cap\operatorname{cl}(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})=\{0\}$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I'm a little confused as to what that shows

Comment: It shows that the point $0$ is a boundary point of the set $\{0\}$. It’s obviously not an accumulation point, however, since $\{0\}$ has no accumulation points.

Comment: Any point that isn't an accumulation point (but is in the set) is an isolated point

Comment: @BrianM.Scott right of course thanks

Answer (score 0):

$p$ is an accumulation point of $S$ iff every nbhd $U$ of $p$ contains a point $q\in U$ \ $\{p\}$. And $p$ is an isolated point of $S$ iff $p\in S$ and $p$ has a nbhd $V$ such that $V\cap S=\{p\}.$ So if $p$ is an isolated point of $S$ and the set $\{p\}$ is not open then $p\not \in $Int$(S)$ and $p$ is not an accummulation point of $S,$ but also $p\in S\subset \bar S.$ For example with the usual topology on $\mathbb R$ let $S=\{0\}.$ Then $S$ has no accummulation points and $S$ has empty interior but $\bar S=S\ne \phi.$